# How works modulo in python?

Tags: python, modulo

Why 
`-4%5 => 1 //I understand
-5%5 => 0 //I understand
-6%5 => 4 // My mind has been deleted`

I checked it in c/cpp, there result is just -1.

Comment: I couldn't find adequated topic.

Answer (score 1):

`-6`: the  biggest number that is less or equal to `-6` and evenly divisible by `5` is `-10`.

```
# just like the other examples
-4 - (-5) == 1  
-5 - (-5) == 0  
-6 - (-10) == 4  # fits perfectly in there
-7 - (-10) == 3  
-8 - (-10) == 2
```

Comment: You defined intreger floor division as done by Python 2.

Comment: @KlausD. Yeah, I noticed that and reverted to my previous version ;)

Comment: So it is more like substraction, than like modulo. [(-10) - (-6)] Weird.

Comment: It is just how modulo, at least in Python, works. If you continue that series into the positive numbers, you will see that it is just the regular continuation.

Comment: I found solution, if i used math.fmod(-6,5) it works. The result is -1, what is correct.